Resizing CupertinoNavigationBar don't work with PreferredSize
I'm trying to change the height of the CupertinoNavigationBar for my flutter app. I tried to do it with PreferredSize (like in material app) but unfortunately it doesn't work.
CupertinoPageScaffold(
      navigationBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(70.0),
        child: CupertinoNavigationBar(),
      ),
      child: Text('content'),
    );

Error: The argument type 'PreferredSize' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ObstructingPreferredSizeWidget?'
So, how can this be done for iOS?

You can implement ObstructingPreferredSizeWidget like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/74255043/2179571 , In source code height is a fixed value https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/6caae154a9499fc06d82915b16287e6f1bcd8d9a/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/nav_bar.dart#L27

As per CupertinoPageScaffold documenation you not declare PreferredSize as navigationBar, you can used CupertinoNavigationBar as navigationBar.
CupertinoPageScaffold expects an ObstructingPreferredSizeWidget? for its navigationBar property, not a PreferredSize. Remove the PreferredSize You can directly use CupertinoNavigationBar as the navigationBar without wrapping it in PreferredSize.
Refer below code:
MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: CupertinoPageScaffold(
    navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
      middle: Text('Cupertino Page Scaffold Sample'),
    ),
    child: Center(
      child: Container(
        child: Text('content'),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)

